# Reset data to the original values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my application I have a lot of attributes inside my data. When I click on a button I need to reset the data to the original values, since I’m manipulating them along the app. Is there a proper way to just turn the data values into the original?

```
data: {
        showStart: true,
        isYouAttack: true,
        valueMonster: 100,
        valueYou: 100,
        monsterProgress: 500,
        youProgress: 500,
        alerts: [],
        progressMonster: {
            'width': '500px',
            'backgroundColor': 'green',
            'height': '50px'
        },
        progressYou: {
            'width': '500px',
            'background-color': 'green',
            'height': '50px'
        }
    },
```

This is the data I’m changing along the application. When I click the button I want to have this data again. Is there an easy way using Vue.js?

Answer (score 1):

If required, a deep clone of the original object can be obtained by passing *vm.$data* through `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`. That provided by the [Vue.js data API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?#data). The code is like this. You can define a reset method on created callbacks. And then call reset methods that will trigger the property that has changed.

### Resettable Component

```
let user = new Vue({
    data: function () {
        return {
            name: 'John',
            address: {
                country: 'China',
                city: 'guangzhou'
            }
        };
    },
    created(){
        let json = JSON.stringify(this.$data);
        this.reset = () => {
            Object.assign(this.$data, JSON.parse(json));
        };
    }
});
```

### Test

```
test('reset deep copied data & trigger the property changed!', (done) => {
    expect(user.address.city).toEqual('guangzhou'); // Initialed data

    user.address.city = 'hunan';

    expect(user.address.city).toEqual('hunan');

    user.$watch('address.city', (newValue, oldValue) => {
        expect(newValue).toEqual('guangzhou');
        expect(oldValue).toEqual('hunan');
        done();
    });

    user.reset(); // Reset methods will trigger property changed.
    expect(user.address.city).toEqual('guangzhou');
});
```

Comment: thaught vueJS provided a easy and fast way, well i try that out